# PowerShell - XML - Handling Nodes with and without attributes

Tags: xml, powershell

I have to change the innertext of an XML node. But the XML node can come in various states such as:

```
<MachineID>1234</MachineID>
```

or

```
<MachineID issuer="companyA">1234</MachineID>
```

or

```
<MachineID issuer="">1234</MachineID>
```

and they can be empty

```
<MachineID />
```

I'm trying to find a better way of handling this than:

```
$count = 0;
try{
    $XMLNode = $Value;
}
catch{
    $count++;
}
try{
    $XMLNode.InnerText = $Value;
}
catch{
  $count++;
}
try{
    $XMLNode.'#text' = $Value;
}
catch{
    $count++;
}
if($count -gt 2){
    echo ("Failed to set " + $XMLNode.Name + " to " + $Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like node selection is the main issue here. The following works for me in your test cases.

```
# Assuming your xml content is in the file file.xml
$x = [xml](Get-Content file.xml)
$Value = 27000
$x.SelectSingleNode('//MachineID').InnerText = $Value
```